# Select Statement returns wrong results

Tags: sql, hana

I have a sub query that returns many columns and there is row_number inside it

[image: Sub Query with many Columns]

when I try to select only two columns it returns wrong results in the row number column

the result should be

| CheckKey | RowNum |
| --- | --- |
| 1936 | 66 |
| 1936 | 81 |

but it returns

| CheckKey | RowNum |
| --- | --- |
| 1936 | 66 |
| 1936 | 76 |

[image: Selection of 2 Columns only]

this is the query :

```
SELECT Z."CheckKey", Z."RowNum" FROM
                (SELECT 
                  X."Transaction Number", 
                  X."Debit", 
                  X."Credit", 
                  X."Balance", 
                  X."CardName", 
                  X."Memo", 
                  X."CheckNum",
                  X."CheckSum", 
                  X."Canceled", 
                  X."Account", 
                  X."RefDate", 
                  X."DueDate", 
                  X."CheckKey",
                  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY X."RefDate" DESC) "RowNum", 
                  CASE
                    WHEN (
                      X."StornoToTr" IS NOT NULL
                      AND X."Deposited" = 'C'
                    ) THEN 'Deposited'
                    WHEN X."Deposited" = 'N' THEN 'Canceled'
                    ELSE X."Status"
                  END "Status"
                FROM CheckKeys X)Z
            WHERE Z."CheckKey" = '1936'
```

Comment: pictures are not helpful.  It is clear in your example that you have two tables -- one alias "X" one alias "Z" -- what is the difference between them?  did you mean X or did you mean Z -- how are you joining them --etc etc.  We need to actually see all the code to know what is going on.

Comment: There is no joining it is just a sub query "That return many columns" called 'Z' then i select only two columns from this sub query

Comment: This is the sql from your impage `SELECT Z.CheckKey, Z.RowNum FROM ( SELECT X."Transaction Number", X.Debit"` you do see the Z and the X prefix there right -- there is no way for us to know what you are selecting from -- there is no way to answer your question unless you show us all the code -- if it is as you say then make a small example with just the columns that matter and show the whole code -

Comment: Sorry i have updated the question with the query

Comment: I see -- so there are 5 extra rows counted by row number() that you don't know what they are -- that is easy -- just change the where to 'WHERE rownum between 66 and 81" and you will see all the rows and know why you have the extra ones.

Comment: The Result is Wrong it give me another CheckKey

Comment: Is there more addition to the query? Cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: You sort only by `RefDate` so identical values of `RefDate` are sorted in random order. That's why you can have unstable results.

Comment: Also you should get the execution plan (via PlanViz) of the query to figure out the step where HANA switches from column engine to row engine to calculate`row_number()`. It can happen after the projection of columns `CheckKey` and `RefDate`, so the number of rows can be already reduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asentx said
sorting only by RefDate so identical values of RefDate are sorted in random order. That's why I get unstable results when I add another column in ordering by like "Transaction Number" the results become stable

Thanks all